# Example of a Discriminative Bayesian Model

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, modeling, inference

While reading through the differences between Generative vs Discriminative; Bayesian vs. Frequentist, I was able to classify the probabilistic models into a table. On further searching on Google, I was able to find a similar table being proposed: https://lingpipe-blog.com/2013/04/12/generative-vs-discriminative-bayesian-vs-frequentist/

$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c}
 & \text{Frequentist} & \text{Bayesian}\\
\hline
Discriminative & {\quad\quad P(Y; x, \theta)\\\text{Linear Regression}\\\text{Logistic Regression}\\\text{GLMs}} & P(Y, \Theta; x) = P(Y | \Theta; x)*P(\Theta) \\
\hline
Generative & {\quad\quad\quad P(Y, X; \theta)\\\text{Linear Discrimant Analysis}\\\text{Quadratic Discrimant Analysis}} & {P(Y, X, \Theta) = P(Y, X | \Theta)*P(\Theta)\\\text{Latent Dirichlet Allocation}} \\
\end{array}
$$

Convention:

1. $Y$ is dependent variable (continuous/discrete), $X$ are a set of independent variables and $\theta$ are model parameters. Capital letter denotes RV and small letters denotes elements that are not modeled probabilistically.
2. Items to the right of `;` are not modeled probabilistically.

**Questions**:

1. Are there standard models that can be categorized as Bayesian Discriminative? By standard, I mean models that people in the Machine Learning or Statistics community would know.
2. What other standard models can be placed in this table?

***Auxiliary Question***:

a. Can we also classify parameter estimation methods like MLE, MAP, MCMC, EM, etc. for this table? For example, I think MLE would fall under Frequentist models and MAP under Bayesian models. Similarly, MCMC would be more suited for Generative models and EM (assuming Y is latent now) would fall under all categories except Discriminative-Frequentist.

PS: I will continue updating the table based on answers.

Comment: I think you are looking for so-called hybrid models that leverage both advantages from Bayesian and frequentist approaches.

Comment: just search for 'bayesian + ' linear regression/ logistic ...

Comment: @seanv507: Thank you. What other models do you suggest that I can put in this table?

Comment: Any model that you put a prior on the coefficients. So all your discriminative ones so far.. eg logistic regression. Also penalized regression models L2 norm etc typically have a representation as mode of  corresponding Bayesian model distribution