# Why do Bayesians not model the input as a random variable in discrminative models?

Tags: probability, bayesian

From this question: [Example of a Discriminative Bayesian Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328666/example-of-a-discriminative-bayesian-model)

There is this table comparing Frequentist/Bayesians and Discriminative/Generative models.
$$\begin{array}{l|c|c}
 & \text{Frequentist} & \text{Bayesian}\\
\hline
Discriminative & {\quad\quad P(Y; x, \theta)\\\text{Linear Regression}\\\text{Logistic Regression}\\\text{GLMs}} & P(Y, \Theta; x) = P(Y | \Theta; x)*P(\Theta) \\
\hline
Generative & {\quad\quad\quad P(Y, X; \theta)\\\text{Linear Discrimant Analysis}\\\text{Quadratic Discrimant Analysis}} & {P(Y, X, \Theta) = P(Y, X | \Theta)*P(\Theta)\\\text{Latent Dirichlet Allocation}} \\
\end{array}$$

Convention:

is dependent variable (continuous/discrete),  are a set of independent variables and  are model parameters. Capital letter denotes RV and small letters denotes elements that are not modeled probabilistically.
Items to the right of ; are not modeled probabilistically.

In the Bayesian, Discriminative cell, why do we not have $P(Y, \Theta \mid x)$? I thought Discriminative models wanted to model the probability of a class, *given* an input.

Comment: Isn't $P(Y,\Theta;x)$ in the Bayesian & Discriminative cell? Is your question about the $;$ notation vs the $|$ notation?

Comment: @dipetkov My question is why we use the $;$ notation here and not the $\mid$ notation in the B & D cell. Why do we **not** write $P(Y, \theta \mid x)$?

Comment: The notation for "conditional on" is not universally agreed upon. For example, the Wikipedia on [Likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Discrete_probability_distribution) diplomatically explains that  the probability of "the value $x$ of $X$ for the parameter value θ is written as P(X = x | θ) or P(X = x; θ)". Here is more: [Probability conditional on a parameter?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/373466/237901).